# run-time 424 error opening userform from commandbox_click

Tags: excel, vba

I've been searching and can't find what the cause of my error is. 
I'm creating a VBA application in Excel to assist in processing financial reports. I have the basic functionality complete and am trying to build an Admin function to allow end users to log in and change the multiplier in the equation. 
I have 2 userforms, frmLogin and frmAdmin.

frmLogin - is very basic, however when it tries to do frmAdmin.Show i get the run-time 424 error.

frmLogin

```
Private Sub LoginButton_Click()
If Me.txtUsername.Value = "Admin" Then
    If Me.txtPassword.Value = "password" Then
        Unload Me
        frmAdmin.Show
        Exit Sub
    Else
    MsgBox "Sorry, Incorrect Login Details"
    Me.txtUsername.SetFocus
    End If
Else
MsgBox "Sorry, Incorrect Login Details"
Me.txtUsername.SetFocus
End If
End Sub
```

frmAdmin

```
Private Sub Save_Click()
Workbook_Refresh
SaveBackup
SaveSettings
CloseForm
End Sub

Private Sub Update_Click()
civa.Value = Sheets("Settings").Range("b1")
oral.Value = Sheets("Settings").Range("b2")
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Settings.Range("b2") = civa.Value
Settings.Range("b3") = oral.Value
End Sub

Private Sub SaveSettings()
ActiveWorkbook.Save SaveChanges:=True
End Sub

Private Sub CloseForm()
Application.Goto Worksheets("Home Screen").Range("D4")
Unload Me
End Sub
```

WorkbookRefresh is called from Module1.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Steven

Comment: Why do you have `Settings.Range("b2") = civa.Value`?  What is `civa.Value` before you have even opened the form?  I'm assuming that `civa` is some sort of control in `frmAdmin`.  Perhaps that line should be reversed?

Comment: Thanks @OpiesDad that was reversed and i made it Sheets("Settings") and it appeared to fix the issue.

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Save` doesn't take any parameters.  You should remove `SaveChanges:=True`

Comment: @OpiesDad either you or the OP should post an answer ao that the OP can close the question.

Answer (score 0):

`Settings.Range("b2") = civa.Value` doesn't make sense in the `UserForm_Initialize()` event.

As `civa` is a control on the form, it doesn't have a value yet, so you can't use it to assign a value to a cell in your sheet.

Instead, I think you meant `civa.Value = Settings.Range("b2")`